# linux command to remove a column, add id column and add another extra column unix/linux awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a tab delimited file, I'd like to re-format it and delete the original, all into one line.

It is a tab-delimited file, I'd like for example to:

remove a given column (i.e., column 3), 
add another id column in the middle (i.e., btw columns 1 and 2) where each line is an id (e.g. row1 is id1, row2 is id2, etc...), and then 
add another column at the end with text (i.e., text where each row is hello).

All changes in one line, and finally delete the original file, and the new file with the same as the original.

Example:

**fnamein.txt**

```
rogelio\tdelgado\t3453434\tlas encinas\n
mario\tmoreno\t4563432\tcasinos\n
etc...
```

**fname.out**

```
rogelio\tid1\tdelgado\t3453434\tlas encinas\taddress\n
mario\tid2\tmoreno\t4563432\tcasinos\taddress\n
etc...
```

(as you can see i added id column btw col 1 and 2, and address column (always same word) at the end).

Just wondering is there is an easy way to do that in linux, i am new to the power of linux commands.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a line (or two) of the original file and then show what the new file should look like after the modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use awk

```
awk -F'\t'  '{print $1, $2, $3}'   filename
```

where -F is the field separator. awk will separate the file into the respective fields and all you need to do is to print the fields. $1 is first field etc.  To skip a field, omit it.

```
awk '{print $1, $3}'  filename
```

will only print the first and the third fields.

Comment: thanks.  it's a partial answer, almost there, but how'd I add a column with id, where row 1 is id1, row2 is id2, etc...  Also how'd I erase the original file and replace it with the new one, in the same line?

Comment: i corrected most of it, but how'd I save it to a file with the same name, all in one line.  If I try awk -F'\t' ''{id++}' {print $1, "id"id, $2, $3, "address"}' filnamein.txt > filenamein.txt, then filenamein.txt would be empty... any ideas?

Comment: awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
perl -i -pwe 's/^([^\t*])\t([^\t*])\t[^\t*]\t(.*)/$1\tid$.\t$2\t$3\taddress/;' FILENAME
```

Comment: perl is an overkill, regexp is an overkill

Comment: As far as I know perl is not part of Linux

Answer (score 1):

Well, unixrules answered helped me to answer the entire question:

awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {id++}{print $1,"id"id,$2,$3,$4,"address"}' filein.txt > test.tmp && mv test.tmp filein.txt.

These answer does exactly what I intended to do originally.

Thanks all for your help.